# Endogenous weights and 2sls

Tags: econometrics, instrumental-variables, weighted-regression

Let's say I have two variables x and y that are both correlated with an omitted variable. I also have an exogenous variable, z, that I can use to instrument for x.

However, for whatever reason I want to weight my two-staged least squares regression by weight w, which also is correlated with the omitted variable. Does this make my IV-2SLS estimate biased?

(n.b. I don't actually want to do this, but I found a paper that does this an I am wondering if it is ok...)

Comment: Can you elaborate on how weights can be endogenous? I am having a hard time wrapping my mind around that, but it sounds interesting.

Comment: Say, the unit of observation is a country and I weight by population, but I think population is correlated with the omitted variable that is causing the endogeneity problem problem,

Comment: Are you able to let us know what the paper is?